# Como evitar que la fila de la clase actualizada cambie de posicion en un array de clases?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Cordial saludo, tengo un programa de clases fitness con un ruby on rails y react, al reservar una clase hice que el numero de quotas de la clase de reduzca en uno para cada reserva, el problema pasa cuando queda actualizada en la tabla ya que se mueve de posicion, necesito que la clase quede en la posicion(fila) que estaba.

Este es el componente de clases y en la funcion ClassBooking esta la parte donde utilizo axios put para actualizar la clase en la que solo cambia el numero de quotas:

````
    const [ class_avs, setClass_avs ] = useState([])
    const [ class_av, setClass_av ] = useState({name: '', date: '', quotas: ''});
    
    useEffect(() => {

            axios.get('/api/v1/class_avs')
            .then( res => {
                setClass_avs(res.data)
            })
            .catch( res => console.log(res) )
    }, [class_avs.length])

        const csrfToken = document.querySelector('[name="csrf-token"]').content;
            axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = csrfToken

        let navigate = useNavigate();

    function ClassBooking(class_av, e) {

        let quotas = class_av.quotas

            if(quotas>=1){
                
                let quo = quotas -= 1;
                let id = class_av.id;
                const updateClas = { name: class_av.name, date: class_av.date, quotas: quo }
                
                axios.put(`/api/v1/class_avs/${id}`, updateClas)
                .then((res) => {
                    console.log(res.data)
                })
                .catch( res => console.log(res))
            }else{
                window.alert('Los cupos para esta clase se han acabado');
                return;
                }
            
            axios.post('/api/v1/bookings', class_av)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                }).catch( res => console.log(res))

        navigate('/bookings');

        } ```
Este es el codigo de la tabla en el componente de las clases, cada clase tiene tres propiedades, solo actualizo quotas por medio de onClick en un button:

<table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Fecha</th>
                            <th>Cupos</th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {class_avs.map(class_av => (
                            <tr key={class_av.id} className="fileFill">
                                <td>{class_av.name}</td>
                                <td>{class_av.date}</td>
                                <td>{class_av.quotas}</td>
                                <td><button onClick={(e) => ClassBooking(class_av, e)}>Reservar</button></td>
                                <td><button onClick={(e) => ClassDelete(class_av.id, e)}>Eliminar</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>

Esta imagen muestra la vista de la lista de clases, cuando reservo una clase se disminuye una quota pero se cambia la posicion de la fila, la clase pasa a la ultima posion o al medio o a la primera posicion, nose porque..

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N74O5.png
````

Comment: Pues se podría mantener ordenado ya sea por id/name/fecha, si pudieras compartir el codigo donde renderizas la tabla.

Comment: Vale, lo acabo de editar con el codigo de la tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede ordenar el array `class_avs` por algún parámetro en particular antes de renderizar, a continuación se ordena por `name`, puede que tengas que adaptar el ejemplo a tu código:

```js
let initState = [
  {id:0, name:"Aerobicos", date:"2022-03-20", quotas:9},
  {id:1, name:"Yoga", date:"2020-04-02", quotas:8},
  {id:2, name:"Karate", date:"2020-04-13", quotas:10}
]

function App() {
  const [ class_avs, setClass_avs ] = React.useState(initState)
  
  function sortAsc(){
    return class_avs.sort(function(a, b){
      let x = a.name.toLowerCase();
      let y = b.name.toLowerCase();
      if (x < y) {return -1;}
      if (x > y) {return 1;}
      return 0;
    });
   
  }
  
  return (
    <div >
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Nombre</th>
              <th>Fecha</th>
              <th>Cupos</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {sortAsc().map(class_av => (
              <tr key={class_av.id} >
                  <td>{class_av.name}</td>
                  <td>{class_av.date}</td>
                  <td>{class_av.quotas}</td>
              </tr>))}
          </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

#### Notas de campo

- Una vez que `React` entra en el `return`, la función `sortAsc` devuelve el estado `class_avs` ordenado por nombre alfabeticamente.
- Lo mismo pasara cada que se re-renderize el componente, garantizando así el orden alfabético de la tabla por nombre.
- El ejemplo de sort esta disponible en la pagina de [ww3school](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp), ahi también hay demos de cómo ordenar por `quotas` por ejemplo, que es de `type number`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya lo implemente y funciona.

Comment: Que bien, no olvides [votar y aceptar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) la respuesta si consideras que fue de ayuda, saludos